# OVS L3 Routing with mininet

Tags: openflow, sdn, openvswitch

I am trying to make mininet topology L3 OVS OF13 such as:

> sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --topo linear,2 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13

- H1: IP 10.0.0.1/24
- H2: IP 10.0.1.1/24

Add route:

- h1 route add default gw 10.0.0.254
- h2 route add default gw 10.0.1.254

I add the following flows:

> - sh ovs-ofctl add-flow -OOpenflow13 s1 priority=500,dl_type=0x800,nw_src=10.0.0.0/24,nw_dst=10.0.1.0/24,actions=normal
> - sh ovs-ofctl add-flow -OOpenflow13 s2 priority=500,dl_type=0x800,nw_src=10.0.1.0/24,nw_dst=10.0.0.0/24,actions=normal
> - sh ovs-ofctl add-flow -OOpenflow13 s1 arp,nw_dst=10.0.0.1,actions=ouput:1
> - sh ovs-ofctl add-flow -OOpenflow13 s2 arp,nw_dst=10.0.1.1,actions=ouput:1

In the interface s1-eth1 IP 10.0.0.254 and interface s2-eth1 IP 10.0.1.254. i do ping to see connection but i have always **Destination Host Unreachable**
Can anyone help me thanks..

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to configure IP address on the switch data ports. The IP addresses on the data ports should ideally be configured using OpenFlow, that is, we should add flows in such a way that the controller responds to the ARP requests for default gateway IP address. Please refer to the link https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Router-Exercise.

If you configure IP address on the data ports of the switch, you will have to setup complete routing in Linux, that is, you will need to enable forwarding on the switches possibly the IP addresses on the interfaces connecting the two switches.